# How do I rotate the Y of this object according to the Y of the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate the Y of my gameobject "Person" according to the Y rotation of "Person/Camero". I thought this would work but it doesn't, why doesn't this work? How could I fix it?
Also, this script is in "Person".

```
transform.rotation.y = GameObject.Find("Person/Camero").transform.rotation.y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

**1**.You are modifying `transform.rotation.y` directly. You **can't** do this and will get the compile-time error like below:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.rotation' because it is
>   not a variable

You have to get `transform.rotation` which is `Quaternion`, modify the `y` then assign that modified `Quaternion` back to `transform.rotation`.

Something like this should compile

```
//Get rotation 
Quaternion tempRot = transform.rotation;
//Modify the Y
tempRot.y = GameObject.Find("Person/Camero").transform.rotation.y;
//Assign back to transform.rotation
transform.rotation = tempRot;
```

but will **not** run properly. See **#2** below for reason.

**2**. The `transform.rotation.y` field is returned in a `Quaternion` form so as the `GameObject.Find("Person/Camero").transform.rotation.y`. Modifying just one axis will **not** give you what you actually expect since it's a `Quaternion`. You have to do this with **angles** instead.

This is done with the `transform.localEulerAngles` or `transform.eulerAngles` properties instead of `transform.rotation`. Use `transform.localEulerAngles`  if the object has a parent Object.

This is what should compile and work as exepected:

```
//Get rotation in Angle deg
Vector3 tempAngle = transform.localEulerAngles;

//Modify the Y axis
tempAngle.y = GameObject.Find("Person/Camero").transform.localEulerAngles.y;

//Assign back to transform.eulerAngles
transform.localEulerAngles = tempAngle;
```

Comment: Thanks a billion @Programmer ! This works flawlessly and your explanations were really easy to understand!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should never trie to rotate something by Hand. Instead finde the delta and use the Rotate function.

Try this:

```
var toRotate = GameObject.Find("Person/Camero").transform.rotation.ToAngleAxis() - transform.rotation.ToAngleAxis();
toRotate.x = 0;
toRotate.z = 0;
transform.Rotate(toRotate);
```

if he looks towards instead of away from the Camera add this line;

```
toRotate.y += 180;
```

Good Luck :)